# Not able to use a two-binding in Directive in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

I am using a controller like this

```
  app.controller('EmployeeCrtl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('/Data/EmployeeDetails.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.EmployeeData = data;
    }).error(function() {
      alert('error');
    });

    //check employee details value
    $scope.insertEmployeeDetails = function(emp) {
      debugger;
      if (emp.EmployeeName !== '' && emp.Designation !== '' && emp.Email !== '' && emp.Address !== '' && emp.PhoneNumber !== '') {
        if (emp.EmployeeName !== undefined && emp.Designation !== undefined && emp.Email !== undefined && emp.Address !== undefined && emp.PhoneNumber !== undefined) {
          debugger;
          $scope.EmployeeData.push(emp);
          this.emp = {};
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

and i have a directive like this

```
 app.directive('addEmployee', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     templateUrl: '/Template/AddEmployee.html',
     link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
       debugger;
     },
     controller: 'EmployeeCrtl',
     scope: {
       insertEmployeeDetails: "&",
       EmployeeData: "="
     }
   };
 });
```

Now what i am trying to do is, when i call the **insertEmployeeDetails** function i push the **EmployeeData** with the new data, but in this i get an error like this
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql7x9.png)
can anyone help me on how to remove this error, i actually want the data which is added in the **EmployeeData** property to be bound in the table which i use

Comment: If EmployeeCrtl is the controller for your directive then EmployeeData and  insertEmployeeDetails  are already in scope for the directive.  Don't pass them in as if they are attributes of the directive.

Comment: you mean to say that i dont have to use  controller: 'EmployeeCrtl', in my directive??? then how will the directive find the directive?

Comment: you are right removing it worked for me, but my question is how do the directive come to know about the controller and its scope

Comment: Its either/or.  If you assign a controller then your directive will work with the scope of the controller.  If you pass variables into your directive's isolate scope as attributes then it will use those variables.